# JMX remote monitoring of Tomcat on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jconsole

I'm trying to hook up **jconsole** with the Tomcat web server deployed on `AWS` `EBS` but I can't get my head around how to setup `Tomcat` to for remote access.

There are few tutorials out there like this [one](https://gist.github.com/diegopacheco/18b4cd9fa4c7c938835027c8d1ec6b8b) that describes how to install & configure a `Tomcat server` on an `EC2` instance. That works beautifully but I want to use the `EBS`'s `Tomcat web server`.

I followed all steps including the creation of the **setenv.sh** file. Unfortunately, `EBS` ignores any setup file at startup and therefore I get the following error when I try to start the web server:

```
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jmxremote.access (No such file or directory)
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: jmxremote.access (No such file or directory)
```

I tested it on my local `Tomcat server` and everything works as expected. If I remove the `setenv.sh` file from the `/bin` folder I get the same error message that confirms my suspicion.

After searching the `web` for a while I came across the [ebextension](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) that would allow me to setup the following props, which is needed for `Tomcat` to load the `catalina-jmx-remote.jar` file.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

Since I could not find any examples how to setup **JMX remote** on `EBS` with the `.config` file or otherwise, I'm wondering whether someone here in the community has successfully hooked up **jconsole** with `EBS`.

Thanks

Comment: `ebextensions` is just bunch of shell scripts to copy over the config file to the beanstalk locations.

Comment: @chenrui - Yes I know but it seems `EBS` is looking into the `.ebextensions` folders and execute scripts from there at startup. Can you confirm?

Comment: yes, you are right, but it does have difference between instance level and tomcat container level.

Comment: @chenrui what would be your guess how to execute the **-D** env vars described in my first post?

Comment: can you show me what you did in your ebextensions? we can go from there. Another thing to note is you need to put `.ebextensions` in the `webapp` folder, so that beanstalk can pick it up.

Comment: @ThomasDittmar are you able to resolve this issue? I managed to add these parameters from Beanstalk web console. but it does not assure that JMX is configured or not. nither I am able to connect.